# Resizeing a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, resize, suppress

I have one crystal report. In this report I have 10 sections in report footer.
report footer1 .... report footer10;

Every section contains data. I have suppress formula at each section base on data. Ex. this formula is for one of my section " {#RTotal8} = 0 "

So until here every thing is ok. If I don't have data in each section, that section does not appear it hides.

But if every 10 sections hide or most of them, I have white space.

I want for each section that hide, my report resize.

(I want default size with consider of all section, and if all section appear so we have no white space, but if each section hide i want my report resize too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the blank section 
In section expert there is option to suppress blank section of the report